# Updating heading tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have several heading tags with IDs named 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3' etc.

```
<h3 id="Cat1"></h3>
```

After an Ajax call a function receives an array of category names and this array is passed into another function which I want to use to place each of the categories from the array, into each of the heading tags. This is what I have at present:

```
    for(var x=0; x<category_array.length; x++) {
        var word = category_array[x];
        var identify = "Cat" + (x+1).toString();
        document.getElementById(identify).innerHTML = word;
        }
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Firstly, why is this occuring and secondly, how can I successfully update my heading tags with each of the categories in the array?

EDIT: If I write 'Cat1' into the getElementById script, it will update the h3 tags. But, the variable identify does not seem to be read correctly.

Comment: We'll need to see a [mcve]. All I can tell you form this code is that `document.getElementById(identify)` is `undefined`. One **possible** cause is multiple items with the same `id`

Comment: What you get in category_array array? Can you show it in question?

Comment: @Liam, using `getElementById()` on elements with the same ID still selects one of the elements, it doesn't return `null`. The only time when it [returns `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Return_value) is when the element cannot be found.

Comment: If the HTML is invalid (which multiple id's is) then all bets are off on how any javascript engine works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because `document.getElementById(identify)` [returns `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Return_value), which happens when the element you're trying to find does not exist. Otherwise, your code looks correct.

Make sure you have enough `Cat<N>` elements on the page to fill. One way to debug this issue is to `console.log(identify)` then look at the HTML to see if you have all the elements that appear in the console.